# Why the new line is printing in the pattern

Tags: java

I'm just learning patterns logics and below is the one of the pattern problem I'm able to write the logic but unfortunately getting wrong answer PFA.

Below is the pattern need to print.

[image]

The same code is working fine in the another online compilers but the same code is printing result differently in the CodeNinjas platform.

I tried in C++ plus as well where the behavior is same.

Can anyone please let me know the reason for this. I'm surprised seeing this behavior.

[image]

Below is the logic I written.

```
public static void numberCrown(int n) {
    // Write your code here.
    int n1=2*(n-1);
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j+"");
        }
        for(int j=1;j<=n1;j++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j =i; j>=1; j--) {
            System.out.print(j+"");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        n1=n1-2;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you don’t need to write `+""`; you can simply use `System.out.print(j);` Further, instead of `System.out.println("");` you can just write `System.out.println();`. It doesn’t change the output, though. There is no recognizable source for an additional line break in the code.

Comment: First line of method: `n = (n < 3 ? 3 : (n > 9 ? n = 9 : n));`. If the supplied argument is less than 3 then make the argument 3. If the supplied argument is greater than 9 then make the argument 9.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine to me. Probably you should select another Java version?

[image]

---

By the way, you can simplify your code:

```java
public static void numberCrown(int n) {
    for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
        for (int colLo = 1, colHi = 2 * n; colHi > 0; colLo++, colHi--) {
            if (colLo <= row)      System.out.print(colLo);
            else if (colHi <= row) System.out.print(colHi);
            else                   System.out.print(' ');
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, but the your optimized code is also giving me a different output 


Not sure what is wrong with this compiler.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the online editor you use?